# Probability using standard deviation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

[image: Probability using standard deviation]

The current through a 1 k
resistor is a Gaussian random variable with mean 10 and standard
deviation 6 (in milliamperes). Calculate the probability that the power dissipated by the resistor
does not exceed 100 milliwatts.

Comment: Do not blank your question after receiving an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the power equation can be written as 
$$ P = I^2 R $$
where you have $R = 1000 \Omega$ and $I$ is given by $\mu = 10mA$,  $\sigma = 6mA$.  The power exceeds $100 mW$ when $ P = I^2 R \geq 0.1 W$ or in other words, when
$$ I \geq \sqrt{\frac{1000}{0.1}} = \sqrt{10000} = 100 A  $$
So the question is, what is the probability that $I \geq 100 A$.

This makes me think that maybe your units are off, because that probability is effectively zero...